# promediate data in columns from csv files

Tags: python, csv, average

I have a problem adding and getting the average for the following csv file with the fieldnames/columns

```
node_code,throughput[Mbps],Data packets_sent,Data_packets lost,rts_cts_sent,rts_cts_lost,node_code,throughput[Mbps],Data packets_sent,Data_packets lost,rts_cts_sent,rts_cts_lost,node_code,throughput[Mbps],Data packets_sent,Data_packets lost,rts_cts_sent,rts_cts_lost
AP_A,111.277485,10618,0,10618,0,AP_B,111.287966,10619,0,10619,0,AP_C,111.287966,10618,0,10618,0
AP_A,111.287966,10619,0,10619,0,AP_B,111.287966,10618,0,10619,0,AP_C,111.287966,10619,0,10619,0
AP_A,111.287966,10619,0,10619,0,AP_B,111.287966,10619,0,10619,0,AP_C,111.298447,10619,0,10620,0
AP_A,111.277485,10618,0,10618,0,AP_B,111.277485,10618,0,10618,0,AP_C,111.298447,10620,0,10620,0
AP_A,111.267004,10617,0,10617,0,AP_B,111.277485,10618,0,10618,0,AP_C,111.287966,10619,0,10619,0
```

and the question is how can I achieve this, add the columns data "throughput[Mbps]","Data packets_sent","Data_packets lost","rts_cts_sent","rts_cts_lost" and generate at the end of the file a line with the averages,like this:

```
node_code,throughput[Mbps],Data packets_sent,Data_packets lost,rts_cts_sent,rts_cts_lost,node_code,throughput[Mbps],Data packets_sent,Data_packets lost,rts_cts_sent,rts_cts_lost,node_code,throughput[Mbps],Data packets_sent,Data_packets lost,rts_cts_sent,rts_cts_lost
AP_A,111.277485,10618,0,10618,0,AP_B,111.287966,10619,0,10619,0,AP_C,111.287966,10618,0,10618,0
AP_A,111.287966,10619,0,10619,0,AP_B,111.287966,10618,0,10619,0,AP_C,111.287966,10619,0,10619,0
AP_A,111.287966,10619,0,10619,0,AP_B,111.287966,10619,0,10619,0,AP_C,111.298447,10619,0,10620,0
AP_A,111.277485,10618,0,10618,0,AP_B,111.277485,10618,0,10618,0,AP_C,111.298447,10620,0,10620,0
AP_A,111.267004,10617,0,10617,0,AP_B,111.277485,10618,0,10618,0,AP_C,111.287966,10619,0,10619,0
average:
AP_A,(  ),(  ),(  ),(  ),(  ),AP_B,(  ),(  ),(  ),(  ),(  ),AP_C,(  ),(  ),(  ),(  ),(  )
```

thanks in advance and i really appreciate the help

Comment: Excel and other spreadsheet software can do this quite nicely.

Comment: in fact, that's the method that i used, but is very hard because i need to do it for a hundred of files, but thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion:

```
import csv

# Collect data for determining the averages
with open('data.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    next(reader)  # Skip first row with headers
    # Initialise sums with first line of data
    sums = [item if item.startswith('AP_') else float(item)
            for item in next(reader)]
    # Sum up the rest of the numbers and count the number of rows with data
    for num, row in enumerate(reader, start=2):
        sums = [item if item.startswith('AP_') else float(item) + number
                for item, number in zip(row, sums)]

# Append averages to the end of the file
with open('data.csv', 'a') as file:
    file.seek(0, 2)  # Go to the end of the file
    file.write('\naverage:\n')
    file.write(','.join(item if type(item) == str else f'({item / num})'
                        for item in sums))
```

My assumption is that the file with the data is named `data.csv`. I've tried to explain what's happening in the comments.